# Why does my for-loop not increase my variable?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I program a batch file, but I'm new to `for-loops` which I need.

I now know how the syntax works, but I cannot figure out why my loop does not do what it should.

This code is an extract from my file:

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p file=: 
set /a numberofgoals=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ("%file%.txt") do set /a "numberofgoals+=1"

echo %numberofgoals%
pause > nul
```

If I did everything right my output *should* be the length of the specified textfile and it worked for me before, but apperently I changed something in the code that I'm not sure about and the output of `%numberofgoals%` is everytime exactly 1 now, regardless of how long my text file is.

My question is: What have I done wrong and why is the output 1 now? I cannot even remember having changed something there...

EDIT: I changed `"delims="` into `"usebackq delims="` as suggested and it works now, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes in the `for` loop's parentheses mean *"process this string"* rather than *"read this file"*.  Use the `usebackq` option to indicate that the quotes are providing a filename:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%file%.txt") do set /a "numberofgoals+=1"
```

and you should be golden.

Type `help for` in your `cmd` window for the gory details.

Comment: As is silence. May be better to add `USEBACKQ` before the `DELIMS` though, and keep the quotes so that filenames that include spaces can be used.

Comment: Oh, you are right of course and this IS what I changed now that I think about it.
When I asked him to open up a file called "With Spaces.txt" (and entered "With Spaces" (without the quotes) to "set /p file=: " it gave me the error "cannot find file Spaces.txt" and it completely left out the "Without " part, so I thought putting it into quotes would change it...
And idea on how I can fix it that way that it runs again (by leabing away the quotation marks as you suggested) but it can still read files with spaces in its name?

Comment: @PeterWright good point. I've updated the answer to use `usebackq` and keep the quotes.

Comment: I just read Peter's answer, but I'm not sure on how the usage of `USEBACKQ` works, but this is exactly what I want, could you please help me with the syntax?

Comment: Thank you, kind sirs!
The program works now just as it should.